# Unable to clear the set interval function

Tags: javascript, timer

I am creating the set interval function for the timer. I successfully implemented the set interval function.

I need to stop the timer using clear interval function. I written the stop_timer function to stop, but i can't able to stop the timer.

I tried it by declaring the empty variable in global. I am not able to get. Below are the code i had tried.

HTML code:

```
<div id="t_demo"></div>
<button onclick="clear_timer()">clear</button>
```

Javascript code:

```
var x = "";

function start_timer() {
  // Update the count down every 1 second
  var x = setInterval(function() {
    var countDownDate = new Date("2019-09-25 05:05:05");
    // Get todays date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();


    // Find the distance between now an the count down date
    var distance = now - countDownDate;



    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
    document.getElementById("t_demo").innerHTML = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;

  }, 1000);

}

start_timer();

function clear_timer() {
  clearInterval(x);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning the interval to a new variable.

Try changing the line

```
var x = setInterval(function() {
```

To

```
x = setInterval(function() {
```

Answer (score 1):

[image: Timer Code]

Global variable x should not be re-declared. See the code below:

```
x = setInterval(function() {...});
```